# Pushing Oauth2 to Github creates gray/not real folders?

Tags: git, github, oauth-2.0

I don't know how to put this properly, so I made it into an image.

[image: oauth2andgithub]

As you can see, on my latest commit, I added some dependencies using Composer. I removed vendor from my .gitignore file, because I am automatically pushing to the website from git.

Anyone had the same problem but knows how to resolve? The folder/files doesn't exist on the site, because github won't add oauth to my repository.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with this approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21022232/1478808

Answer (score 0):

(quick and **dirty**) Fix was pretty simple.

Make sure you can view hidden folders. In windows it's pretty simple:

```
Organize->Folder and search options (or something similar)->Advanced Settings->Show hidden files, folders and drives.
```

Went into vendor/adoy/oauth2, removed the .git folder then pushed to my repository the standard way.

The repository oauth2, (when used with composer) downloads the (hidden) .git folder. I simply deleted it, and it's now working as intended.

I'm not sure how this will affect the composer setup, though, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

> The folder/files doesn't exist on the site, because GitHub won't add oauth to my repository.

It has added `vendor/adoy/oauth2`, as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

When you clone that repo, a simple command will populate that folder:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```